# mysqldump routines charset encoding problem

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, routines, cp1250

How could I possibly dump MySQL database structure and data on windows with **mysqldump** with **polish** characters ("ęóąśłżźćń") included?

So far I've managed to dump it altogether using `mysqldump.exe <my_settings> --default-character-set=cp1250`. It appears to solve at least my data inserts encoding problem since I've set it to **cp1250** (Windows Central European) instead of latin2.

The problematic phrases are within my db structure code. For instance: all my stored procedures and functions contain these "special" characters in their comments. I believe, for some reason, they are interpreted as utf8 instead of cp1250. No matter what encoding I set, my comments stay intact.

I believe there must be some other separate setting for routines charset encoding I'd missed. I know it's possible to achieve since I dumped it with workbench data export and somehow it worked. Sadly I wasn't able to check cnf file content since it disappears right afterwards.

Any help would be much appreciated. Especially one excluding potential script conversions.

Cheers

Comment: Switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Drop the stored routines, `SET NAMES` to the desired charset, re-`CREATE` the routines.

Confirm with `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE name` and look at the charset given at the end.